# Assigning Numpy array to variables

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, variable-assignment

Is there an effective way to assign a Numpy array to a set of variables, each variable being assigned to the subsequent array element?

Pseudocode:

```
[a,b,c,d] = A
```

where `A` is a 2x2 matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [13]: A = np.arange(4).reshape(2, 2)

In [14]: A
Out[14]:
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])

In [16]: A.ravel()
Out[16]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])

In [17]: a, b, c, d = A.ravel()

In [18]: a, b, c ,d
Out[18]: (0, 1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!